# Angular Directive and component

Tags: angularjs

How to develop an app in angular? Also does it support JQUERY files?

Comment: You can use jquery in angular app, but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think directive is the best way.Because we can reuse the same.

Answer (score 0):

Angular contains a subset of jquery functionality, so most of the more commonly used methods are still available (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Components in Angular 1.5 are similar to Directives, but Components are mainly used when you do not need to directly manipulate the DOM within the component, although you can use directives within components to do DOM manipulation. You can include other directives and components within a component, as well.

One is not better than the other, it just depends on what you are trying to accomplish. (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)